# How do I remove Ubuntu from my computer completely, so it is just a blank PC?

Tags: windows-8

So a while back I installed Ubuntu on my laptop. I've recently been using it again but want to re install windows, ive tried many methods but none seem to work. So I want the hardrive wiped completely, so I can re-install that way. Can anyone help me in doing this? Please help me!

Comment: Windows installation didn't let you just delete the partitions and format?

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and the people here are very good at dual-booting and removing Windows, but not very good at getting it back once it was removed...  However, on http://superuser.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at deleting Ubuntu and installing Windows, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with reinstall Windows XP instead of Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/109139/help-with-reinstall-windows-xp-instead-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

You can just wipe your harddisk. There are many tools free or paid for that, you can google it.

But I'm gonna here give you two choices:

1. Use [Gparted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) then delete all partitions
2. Use Ubuntu Live Cd and write zeros to the HDD using `dd` command

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX
   ```

Replace X with yours

Comment: Then i try and delete the partitions using Gparted, it doesnt let me delete the partitions as the delete function is blacked out. Please help!

Comment: you should unmount the partition before. you have to do that from Gparted Live Cd not just from the application, then unmount the harddisk do you can do what you want

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an Ubuntu live USB stick or DVD. I'm assuming you know how to do this already because you managed to install Ubuntu in the first place.
2. Boot up your computer to the USB stick/DVD, choosing 'Try Ubuntu', and open the program 'Disks' from the dash.
3. Click your hard drive on the left hand pane.
4. For each partition listed in the box: in the bottom left, if there is a black square, click it. If there is a black triangle, leave it as-is.

   [image: Disks]
5. Click the menu button in the top right corner of the window.
6. Choose 'Format' and choose `Don't overwrite...` and `Compatible with all systems...`.
7. When this is done, your hard drive will be empty, and you can install Windows.

N.b. this will not *wipe* the hard drive completely, so choose `Overwrite all existing data` if you are going to sell your computer.

Comment: When I try to boot up the PC with a usb, nothing happens and it just loads Ubuntu as it normally does, I have changed the BIOS to boot the USB first. Please help!

Comment: What manufacturer makes your computer?

Comment: Its made by Packard Bell.

Comment: Press F2 while booting to *enable* the boot menu (find the option in the settings), and then press F12 to bring it up when booting. More info: http://packard-bell-scandic.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6814/~/enabling-the-boot-device-menu

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7agxjn I have changed the boot menu to that. So if I'm correct that should boot up using the USB right? But it doesn't it just loads the other copy of ubuntu which is already on the PC. Help?

Comment: Don't permanently change the boot order, just press F12 when booting and choose the right one. Try other options, maybe it's one of the others.

Comment: So I watched that video you sent, and I did all of that but when I pressed f12 it just took me to the GRUB menu, what should I do from there?

Comment: Hmm maybe it's different on your model. Did you 1) press it early enough and 2) enable the boot menu?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7ah177 It takes me here

Comment: Select the first

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7ah2m5 That takes me here

Comment: ok, try the second and see if there's a difference

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7ah46d That comes up with this

Comment: Yes, they're different. Go back to the first one again and boot up to it - that's the USB stick.

Comment: Then just follow the original instructions again :) good luck

Comment: doing that just loads Ubuntu normally :/

Comment: ah no I meant try the second device in the boot menu, not the second item in GRUB. Those two are the same OS... Sorry for being unclear

Comment: That's ok glad to have helped :D